# Let $\lim_{T \to \infty} \int_{0}^{T}e^{-t^2}dt=\sqrt{\pi}/2$, then $\lim_{T \to \infty} \int_{0}^{T}t^2e^{-t^2}dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> Let $\lim_{T \to \infty} \int_{0}^{T}e^{-t^2}dt=\sqrt{\pi}/2$, then
> $\lim_{T \to \infty} \int_{0}^{T}t^2e^{-t^2}dt$
>
> (A) $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}$
>
> (B) $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$
>
> (C) $\sqrt{2\pi}$
>
> (D)$2\sqrt{\pi}$

**Attempt 1:**

First I tried to evaluate,

$ \int_{0}^{T}t^2e^{-t^2}dt=t^2\int e^{-t^2}dt|_{0}^{T}-\int_{0}^{T}t^2$$\int e^{-t^2}dt$ $dt$.

But,
I am not able to proceed further.

After evaluating the integral, I plan to apply $\lim_{T \to \infty}$ on both side.

**Attempt 2:**

Let $t^2=x \implies 2tdt=dx.$

$\int_{0}^{\infty}t^2e^{-t^2}dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{-x}dt=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\pi}$

My first attempt was a failure. In the second attempt, I could obtain the answer. But I didn't use the given condition. Please help me to complete the first attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the wrong integration by parts:
$$
\int t^2e^{-t^2}\,dt=
\frac{1}{2}\int t\cdot 2te^{-t^2}\,dt
$$
Since
$$
\int 2te^{-t^2}\,dt=-e^{t^2}
$$
you can probably finish up.

Comment: Yes! you are right. Thank you very much. @egreg